# Очень распространённая ошибка в словосочетании из двух слов

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, типы-ошибок

Хочу задать нестандартный вопрос. Просьба не голосовать за его закрытие, если кому-то покажется он неподходящим, а подождать, пока я его **перепишу**.

Дело в том, что я заметил, что есть очень распространённая ошибка в словосочетании из двух слов. Если закавычить правильный и неправильный вариант в Гугле, правильный будет лишь немного выигрывать у неправильного по количеству результатов поиска. То есть не исключено, что эта ошибка вообще самая распространённая.

Итак, мне очень хочется, чтобы кто-то догадался, что это за словосочетание. Вопрос будет заключаться в следующем: ***что сделало этот ошибочный вариант таким распространённым? Почему многим хочется так написать?***

Подсказки:

- это *глагол + существительное;*
- это два последних слова известной пословицы из четырёх слов (у последнего изменён падеж);
- ошибка в окончании глагола, на слух сложно уловить разницу;
- типичным высказыванием будет: *"кто-то + это словосочетание".*

---

Итак, речь о выражении *"(кто-то) глаголет истину"* и очень распространённом ошибочном варианте *"глагол**и**т".*

Comment: Хорошо, Артем, давайте заключим сделку. Начнем с того, что в вашем вопросе есть ошибка, и  я думаю, что вы ее легко  найдете. Но за найденную ошибку мне (ну и всем другим тоже) полагается бонус, а именно еще одна подсказка, но уже безо всяких ограничений (то есть любая, проси что хочешь). И что бы мне попросить? Пожалуй, вот что. Назовите мне (полным текстом) пословицу-синоним (антоним) или  хотя бы что-то похожее с той же моралью и на ту же тему.

Comment: @Sharon: ого! Хитро вы придумали!)) Правильно исправил? Может, не очень правильный синоним, но попробуем: *Во всяком мудреце довольно простоты.*

Comment: Не знаю! Все пословицы пересмотрела, а подходящей нет. А вам еще одна штрафная санкция: я имела в виду другую ошибку, более серьезную.  И вот за эту ненайденную ошибку еще одна подсказка (по моему выбору). Назовите существительное.

Comment: Сначала скажите ошибку. Или исправьте, но с уведомлением.))

Comment: .....ошибка в падежном окончании глагола? А у глаголов не бывает падежных окончаний. И тогда непонятно: ошибка в окончании глагола или в окончании существительного, которым глагол управляет?

Comment: Точно! Можно, я скажу не само существительное, а синоним прилагательному от него? Верный.

Comment: Думаете это мне поможет? Ну ладно, говорите.

Comment: Ладно, *истина. :)*

Comment: Устами младенца глаголит/глаголет истина?

Comment: ***Ага!)))))***

Comment: Артем, а что там с этим глаголом? Я была уверена, что есть слово глаголить, а в словаре - глаголать?

Comment: Да, вроде есть только "глагол**а**ть".

Comment: Какой-то странный глагол. Наверное, устаревающая форма, современным людям он не нравится. Поэтому "словаропослушные" пишут  АТЬ  по словарю, а остальные пишут ИТЬ. И что с этим делать?  Задайте вопрос на форуме или у Грамоты спросите.

Comment: Ну ладно, спасибо, что хоть в комментариях обсудили со мной! Было приятно.))

Comment: @Sharon В словаре Ефремовой есть "глаголить".

Comment: Очень хорошо, я не сомневалась, что он где-нибудь есть. "Глаголать" можно только у Кузнецова на Грамоте увидеть. Этот глагол и выговорить-то невозможно, не вписывается он в современную фонетику. Кстати, где вы гуляете, пора уже за работу браться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, интересный вопрос. Прочитав ответ на загадку, решил погуглить в авторитетных источниках. Н. Еськова пишет:

> В «Кратком словаре трудностей русского языка»  (1994)  наряду с
>   **глаголать** (охарактеризованным как устаревшее слово) дается отдельной
>   словарной статьей **глаголить** с комментарием:  «Слово возникло в
>   результате морфологической трансформации устаревшего слова **глаголать**.
>   Основой послужило то, что некоторые формы от **глаголать** и **глаголить**
>   должны быть образованы одинаково (**глаголю**, **глаголь**, **глаголя**), другие —
>   только с разным орфографическим оформлением (**глаголет**, **глаголют**,
>   **глаголющий**, **глаголемый** — от **глаголать**  и **глаголит**, **глаголят**,
>   **глаголящий**, **глаголимый** — от **глаголить**).
>
> Морфологическое переосмысление таких форм приводит к появлению инфинитива **глаголить** (вместо **глаголать**), прошедшего **глаголил** (вместо
>   **глаголал**) и др. Возникшие первоначально как ошибки, эти формы получают
>   распространение, вытесняя правильные формы устаревшего слова
>   «**глаголать**».

Подробнее можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.ruslang.ru/doc/melchuk_festschrift2012/Eskova.pdf).

Comment: Спасибо, Гризли! Даже не думал, что появилось новое слово, вытесняющее исконное.