# Слово "проект" как исключение

Tags: орфография, орфоэпия

Принять нельзя, исключить. **Почему в русском языке так много исключений?**  Вероятно, на это есть  объективные причины. Но почему  исключения  **нужно запоминать, почему их никто не объясняет**? Вот это уже вопрос, на который сложно ответить.

Ну да, для чего нам знать лишнего, мы и необходимое плохо знаем. Мы – всё равно **не поймем!**

И начинается. Написал ***проект*** через Э? Вот безграмотный! – Так слышится же Э, причем  после гласной О, как в слове *поэт,* а Е обычно пишется после И. – **А это – исключение!** В словари надо смотреть.

**Но мы не любим исключения, не любим ничего запоминать** и начинаем фантазировать: ищем проверочные слова и даже находим – *проектировать*, ищем однокоренные слова, понимаем, что русский язык сложный. Просим объяснить, почему?  И делаем вывод, что ответ кто-то знает, да нам не говорит. А молодежь, та и вовсе не заморачивается, в словари не смотрит и пишет – ***проэкт***. Что с них, безграмотных, возьмешь!

Вот, к примеру, цитата: «Недавно также интересовался этим вопросом. Поскольку сам бы убежден, что писать нужно через букву Э. Но это оказалось ошибкой. Действительно, читаем мы Э, но пишем  Е. **А вот только почему? До сих пор загадка».**

Так, может быть, **надо объяснять исключения?** Ведь всё исключительное хорошо запоминается, так как включается эмоциональная память.

**И вопросы:**

А это правда, что сначала (со времен Петра I) это слово писалось как ***проэкт?***  Правда, что эта форма обозначена еще в словаре 1907 года. **Так когда и почему написание решили изменить?**

**Примечания**

1) И вот еще интересная цитата: «Мама моя, когда я был еще школьником, работала диктором. До сих пор помню ее уроки произношения. Так вот она учила, что правильно произносить нужно усредненный **звук между Е и Э**».
А это правда?

2) ***Неграмотный и безграмотный*** – это синонимы? Мне кажется, что у слова *безграмотный* присутствует негативно-экспрессивная окраска. Стоит ли из-за одной ошибки называть человека безграмотным? Может быть, это тоже «неграмотно»?

http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/720401-kak-pravilno-pishetsja-proekt-ili-proekt.html

http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3442517-pochemu-nekotorye-ispolzujut-e-oborotnoe-vmesto-bukvy-e-sm.html

Comment: Ещё не прочитал, но сразу приходит в голову однокоренное слово "проекция". Та же ситуация с Таиландом.

Comment: Ещё приходят в голову "военкомат", "двое", двое- и "своевластие".

Comment: *Так вот она учила, что правильно произносить нужно усредненный звук между Е и Э». А это правда?* Да, по-моему, именно так и надо произносить. Чистый Э не произносят, и вообще, его сложно произнести без отрыва от О. Но и в слове "поэт" тот же усреднённый звук, независимо от того, произносят ли его классически с выраженным О или акая.

Comment: Произношение звука Э зависит от окружения, даже слова этот и эти произносятся немного по-разному. По правилу после И обычно пишется буква Е, это как раз связано со смягчением гласного и даже переходом его в йотированный гласный.К примеру, для слова "диета" в словаре допускаются два произношения: Е и Э.

Comment: Интересно, мне кажется я произношу Е в "диете" и Э в "диетическом". Не пытались разгадать мою загадку отсюда: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457561/%d0%9e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2?

Comment: Артем, у меня не очень получается разгадывать загадки, но ведь и никто пока не отгадал. Несмотря на то что подсказок много, они общего характера и мало помогают. Нужна хотя бы одна конкретная деталь, привязка  к определенной теме.

Comment: А можете спросить что-то? Если мне это не покажется слишком большой подсказкой, тогда скажу. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Наряду с русск. *Проект* — начиная с Петра I; иногда в форме *проэкт* (уже у Шафирова, 1710 г.); вероятно, заимств. через нем. Projekt (с XVII в.), и сейчас вполне употребимо заимствование, ставшее разговорным и ироничным (несерьёзный, ненужный, или несбыточный, неосуществимый, беспочвенный, неосновательный замысел, проект), — *Прожект* — устар. от франц. projet, далее от лат. projectus «брошенный» («*Ага, так это ещё в прожекте находится.*» Ф. М. Достоевский, «Братья Карамазовы», 1880), в котором при позиции после согласной та же Е звучит как Э. Иного звучания при всём желании не получить, и даже «усреднённое».

Рассматривать лишь эти (по всему близкие) слова было бы странным занятием в ходе массового заимствования однотипных — *объект* (позднелат. objectum предмет, от лат. objicio бросаю вперёд, противопоставляю); *субъект* (от лат. subjectus лежащий внизу, находящийся в основе, от sub под и jacio бросаю, кладу основание);  *перфект* (лат. perfectum совершенное, совершённое); *префект* от лат. praefectus от гл. praeficere «ставить впереди, сверху, во главе», в Российском государстве со времён Петра I до 1917 г. — инспектор духовной семинарии, — и им подобных. Тем более — выборочно реконструировать.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Мне понятно, почему в современном правописании используется буква Е. Это метод транслитерации, то есть побуквенное заимствование. Слова объект, субъект, префект имеют один латинский корень, и представляется логичным писать их одинаково. Но  произношение у них разное, поэтому "проект, проектировать, проекция" долгое время писались в соответствии с произношением, что видно из словаря  иностранных слов Павленкова (1907 года). http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/foreign-words-pavlenkov/index.htm#207  А вот что было потом? В словаре Ушакова пишется уже "проект".

Comment: Когда именно было закреплено это написание? История слов интересна сама  по себе. И если бы в учебниках вместо слова исключение приводилась бы эта информация, это пошло бы на пользу всем: и тем, кто учит, и тем, кто учится. Грамотность, я думаю, повысилась бы.